# tenfowflow saved model input feeds name not always same

Tags: tensorflow, input, feed

I use tensorflow C++ API LoadSavedModel load a savedmodel, then generate a CallableOptions instance with input and output feeds name from bundle_.meta_graph_def.signature_def, but input name has two kind of style, as picture shows, is this right?

ps: tf2.8.4

[image]